# scroll in Blackberry access browser

Tags: reactjs, scroll, blackberry

In my react / redux application, on click of a particular button, I want to scroll up at a particular position.

It's working fine in firefox, chrome and Safari. But **it is breaking in Blackberry access browser**.

Can someone provide me the solution for it . I have already used approaches like `window.scroll, scrollTo, scrollIntoView`, 
    jquery approach:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

and `focus()`

All these approaches are not working in Blackberry Access browser.